# TextView and EditText view is not getting displayed

Tags: android, view

Here are the problems that I have :

1. My TextViews are not getting displayed
2. My EditText Views margins are also not getting displayed
3. As the user inputs userName and Password into EditText Field, the cursor keeps 
   moving ahead but no letters are displayed on the screen

   ```
   This is what I expect from my code
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   This is what I get as output
   ```

[image]

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3dcc24">

<include

layout="@layout/log_toolbar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#089da2"
    android:text="Register Later"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/RegisterButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RegisterButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/RegisterButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:background="#089da2"
    android:text="Register Now"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text="Not Registered?"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/LogButton"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#535de2"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="LOG IN"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text="@string/forgot"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Java file

```
public class First extends AppCompatActivity {


int Flag = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarL) ;
    setSupportActionBar(t);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    Button RegButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegisterButton);
    Button  logButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogButton);
    EditText UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    RegButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogInForm.class);

            startActivity(i2);
        }
    });

    logButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });

}


}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[This is what I get from your code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhpyo.png)  Please check if your AppTheme contains some white color that could be applied here.

Comment: Nope ! its #3F51B5

Comment: This is my App Theme
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 </style>

what changes should i make ?

Comment: First of all, please change the background of android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" to black and test the app to see that the text is white.
Second of all, please compare your result to mine (the picture I've posted above) and see that all the text in your result are white and mine are black (default). That's why I asked to check the AppTheme, but it seems it's not it. Do you have any other styles?

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal have you found the problem?

Comment: Nope ! i have shared the style and that is the only theme that i have applied

Answer (score 0):

Your controls is already displayed but with background white color and also the layout so try to change colors like that and they should appears

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3dcc24">

    <include

        layout="@layout/log_toolbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#089da2"
        android:text="Register Later"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/RegisterButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RegisterButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/RegisterButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:background="#089da2"
        android:text="Register Now"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:background="#ddff"
        android:text="Not Registered?"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#FFFF"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
            android:hint="this is edit text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="this is edit text"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#ddff"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#ddff"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="password"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/LogButton"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#535de2"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
            android:text="LOG IN"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
     </RelativeLayout>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/forgot"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout2" />

      </RelativeLayout>
```